# how can i fix my Failed to compile defining error?

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv, crud

i followed a tutorial on exporting data from my react app to a CSV file
but im getting an undefined error:

```
./src/components/index.component.js
  Line 37:9:   'csvRow' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 39:21:  'csvRow' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 39:36:  'OA' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Here is my code for the CSV exporting:

```
csvData: [
          {
            'personName': '',
            'businessName': '',
            'date': '',
            'activity': '',
            'hours': '',
            'learningStatement': ''
          }
        ]
      };
    }

    exportCsv() {
      var cvsRow=[];
      var A = [['person', 'business', 'date', 'activity', 'hours', 'learningStatement']];
      var re = this.state.csvData;

      for(var item=0; item<re.length; item++) 
      {
        A.push([item, re[item].person], re[item].business, re[item].date, re[item].activity, re[item].hours, re[item].learningStatement]);
      }
      // console.log(A);

      for(var i=0; i<A.length; ++i) 
      {
        csvRow.push(A[i].join(","))
      }
      var csvString=csvRow.join(""%OA);

      var a=document.createElement("a");
      a.href='data:attachment/csv.' + csvString;
      a.target='_Blank';
      a.download= 'testfile.csv';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    };
```

i haven't dealt with this kind of functionality so i don't know if i'm on the right track.

Comment: You made a type mistake at `var cvsRow=[];` it should be `csvRow `.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, it says csvRow and OA is not defined. Did you created those variables somewhere before actually accessing them?